# Knapsack dynamic in R

Tags: r, knapsack-problem

I am trying to implement the sudo code from wikepedia in order to solve the knapsack problem but my code fails.
My function takes as input a data frame X with 2 columns,the first was the weights and second the values

```
 weights value
    10   110
    20   150
    15   180
    30   170
    18   130

knapsnack_dyn<-function(X,W){
  w<-c(0,X[,1])
  v<-c(0,X[,2])
  n<-nrow(X)
  m<- matrix(0,nrow=n+1,ncol=W+1)
  keep<-m
  res<-c()
  for (i in 1:n+1){
    for (j in 0:W+1){
      if (w[i]>j ){
        m[i,j]<-m[i-1,j]
        keep[i,j]<-0
      }else{
        m[i,j]<-max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
        keep[i,j]<-1
      }
    } 
  }
  K=W+1
  for (i in n+1:1){
    if(keep[i,K]==1){
      res[i]<-i
      K=K-w[i]
    }
  }
return(c(res,m[n+1,W+1]))
}
```

Comment: I do not know what to expect of this so I did not manage to fix it. However, be advise that with R, when you do this `for(i in n+1:1)`, `i` will take only one value which here is `n+1`. You need parenthesis as the `:` has the priority. So change your loops for things like `for(i in (n+1):1)`, `for (j in 0:(W+1))`...

Comment: @Yo B I did that the problem of my code seems to be in the part of returning the combination I think